# Not able to connect to AWS S3 from React App

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cors

**EDIT**

I've found out through the comments that I was querying the general S3 api instead of the specific buckets api. Doing that from a browser does not work and I got the error I reported here. In order to "fix" that, I simply switched to using the specific buckets API.

I used the same configurations, but instead I called the s3.upload method as in:

```
  const uploadFile = (file) => {
    const uploadParams = { ACL: "public-read", Bucket: config.bucketName, Key: file.name, Body: file };

    s3.upload(uploadParams, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error", err);
      } else {
        console.log("Success", data.Location);
        // setProfilePic(data.location)
      }
    })
  }
```

---

I want to upload a file to S3 from my React app. I am using the "official" aws-sdk module, from following this tutorial: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-creating-buckets.html#s3-example-creating-buckets-scenario

The problem is that I am getting a CORS error right in my first attempt to print my buckets:

```
import AWS from 'aws-sdk'

const config = {
  bucketName: 'train-my-game',
  dirName: 'profile', /* optional */
  region: 'us-east-2',
  accessKeyId: proccess.env.ACCESS_KEY,
  secretAccessKey: proccess.env.SECRET,
}

AWS.config.update({ region: config.region, accessKeyId: config.accessKeyId, secretAccessKey: config.secretAccessKey });
const s3 = new AWS.S3({ apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });

const printBuckets = () => {
  s3.listBuckets(function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Success", data.Buckets);
    }
  });
}
printBuckets()
```

This fails with the error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

In the AWS, my bucket is configured with the following permission XML for the CORS configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>HEAD</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To put objects to a bucket, list objects in a bucket, retrieve bucket policies etc. you need to enable CORS on the target S3 bucket. Read the [CORS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html) documentation or see the example at [awslabs/aws-js-s3-explorer](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-js-s3-explorer).

You will not be able to invoke ListBuckets, however. The reason is that the ListBuckets call is made to an S3 service endpoint (s3.amazonzaws.com), not to an S3 bucket endpoint (bucket.s3.amazonaws.com) and you cannot enable CORS on the S3 service endpoint. So, ListBuckets will never work in a regular browser. Some browsers allow you to suppress CORS, but it's not normal browser operation. Obviously, if your app were to run outside of the browser, e.g. as a CLI or in Electron, then ListBuckets would work fine.

Comment: Thank you, @jarmod. You pointed me to the root cause of my issue and it was my misunderstanding of the different apis I was using. In fact, I went ahead and tried to upload the file straight to the bucket, using the S3 bucket endpoint and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-Origin-Resource-Sharing (CORS) is the mechanism that prevents a web app from running client-side code which makes requests to another web app. Imagine if Facebook could run some javascript and read the email you have in Gmail (because you're already logged in).

To address this, all browsers block javascript from one server from accessing any HTTP resources at any other url/ip unless that URL or IP explicitly allows (trusts) the site that javascript originate from.

In the case of many of the AWS SDK's you must explicitly configure what CORS headers you would like to send when interfacing with your AWS (S3 in this case) Resources.

See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/cors.html

Replace the AllowedOrigin "example.org" with the FQDN of the server serving your react application.

Comment: How can I do that? This request is sent from the browser. This is a client-side application. Should I configure the aws-sdk module to use these headers? That is what I am using to handle the requests

Comment: You need to configure in the S3 bucket (in the AWS console) see: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html#how-do-i-enable-cors

Comment: To provide more context, this behavior is entirely a result of the application being client-side. It is not even a consideration when dealing with serverside applications. The S3 API has to respond to an OPTIONS request with a header of Allow-Origin: yoursite.yourdomain.com. Which basically tells the consumers browser that it is safe for a script coming from yoursite.yordomain.com to communicate with the the S3 API.

Comment: Yes, I have it set up from the beginning. I have edited my question to include the xml that I used in my tests.

Comment: There are significant risks with <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin> so once you get it working make sure you tighten that down to just your server url.

With that said your config is entirely permissive. So long as it is attached to the bucket correctly it should work... You can test that by using postman or some other tool to send an OPTIONS request to the bucket URL. If you were successful you should see matching headers for each of the options in your XML (just keyed slightly different)

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

If you’d like to send Authorization headers, your server had better be configured to allow it. Set your server up so it responds to an OPTIONS request at that url with an Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization header.

Comment: How can I do that? This request is sent from the browser. This is a client-side application.

Comment: The 'server' in this case is Amazon S3.